# How to count JSON values

Tags: python, json, counting

Hi I'm a newbie looking for some help. I have a JSON file (see below), I need to count the number of enabled = true. I have thought about looping through, but I think there is a more efficient way. Then I can output the total.
Thanks Louisa

`Successful HTTP Status: 200

[
  {
    "portId": "1",
    "enabled": true,
    "status": "Connected",
    "errors": [
      "PoE overload",
      "Very high proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "warnings": [
      "PoE port was denied power",
      "High proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "speed": "10 Gbps",
    "duplex": "full",
    "usageInKb": {
      "total": 40867,
      "sent": 23008,
      "recv": 17859
    }
{
    "portId": "2",
    "enabled": true,
    "status": "Connected",
    "errors": [
      "PoE overload",
      "Very high proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "warnings": [
      "PoE port was denied power",
      "High proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "speed": "10 Gbps",
    "duplex": "full",
    "usageInKb": {
      "total": 40867,
      "sent": 23008,
      "recv": 17859
    },
{
    "portId": "3",
    "enabled": true,
    "status": "Connected",
    "errors": [
      "PoE overload",
      "Very high proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "warnings": [
      "PoE port was denied power",
      "High proportion of CRC errors"
    ],
    "speed": "10 Gbps",
    "duplex": "full",
    "usageInKb": {
      "total": 40867,
      "sent": 23008,
      "recv": 17859
    },

,
    "cdp": {
      "systemName": "",
      "platform": "MS350-24X",
      "deviceId": "0c8ddbddee:ff",
      "portId": "Port 20",
      "nativeVlan": 1,
      "address": "10.0,0.1",
      "managementAddress": "10.0.0.100",
      "version": "1",
      "vtpManagementDomain": "",
      "capabilities": "Switch"
    },
    "lldp": {
      "systemName": "MS350-24X - Test",
      "systemDescription": "MS350-24X Cloud Managed PoE Switch",
      "portId": "20",
      "portDescription": "Port 20",
      "chassisId": "0c:8d:db:dd:ee:ff",
      "managementVlan": 1,
      "portVlan": 1,
      "managementAddress": "10.0.0.100",
      "systemCapabilities": "switch"
    },
    "clientCount": 10,
    "powerUsageInWh": 55.9,
    "trafficInKbps": {
      "total": 2.2,
      "sent": 1.2,
      "recv": 1.0
    }
  }
]`

Comment: where is your data?

Comment: Hi. It is better to paste a sample of the json file rather than attaching it

Comment: is this one full json file? it appears to be invalid

Comment: its just an example i`ve been given. the main idea is to count number of occurances of: "enabled": true,